Pink Swelling of puppy spay incision
We picked up our puppy from the vet a couple of hours ago. We didn't check the incision there. But, when we got home, we saw this strange redness and inflammation-like thing on her incision. Is this normal? Should be worried about it?
[]
Our puppy is 7.5 months old.

Looks very similar to this question, only that yours is fresh after the operation. Make sure your dog is not licking the wound excessively or trying to pull the stitches out.

Thank you for your reply. I sent the photo to the vet to see what she will say.

The vet said it's a Seroma and looks normal.
